# Commenting out unused class tells me I have 0% code

Tags: code-coverage

In trying to get better coverage, I want to retire unused classes that have low coverage.
When I try to deploy a commented out version of the class, I get an error:

> Your organization's code coverage is 0%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment. Also, the following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.

I don't see this as possible. If I try to deploy an updated class that still has a body, I get an org percentage that makes sense (73%, which I am trying to improve).

Does anyone understand why I can't retire these classes? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test Classes referencing the deleted class also need to be deleted/ changes.

Comment: While this solved the problem, it does not change the fact the error messages are terribly confusing and unhelpful.

Comment: I had a similar problem: I wanted to deploy some classes after I deleted a deprecated class in my sandbox. Deployment said I have 0% coverage (which is obviously wrong). After deleting the deprecated class in production, the deployment succeeded. Thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy code to production, all of your tests are run, and validation of overall code coverage takes place, as well as by trigger. Each trigger must be exercised in some way by a unit test, otherwise this validation will fail. I think your first step is writing some unit tests for the trigger(s) in question. Also, if you wish to delete classes or triggers, you can deploy those deletions by deploying your entire classes and triggers directories, minus the deleted metadata, from your sandbox. Beware though that your sandbox accurately represents production, because this will overwrite all classes and trigger in production with what is in your sandbox.

Comment: I have tests for all the triggers in question. They all have various degrees of coverage when I try to deploy a new class. it is only when I try to deployed a commented out class that I see them as having 0.

Comment: Have you looked to see where the classes are being used? It sounds as though these classes are perhaps being called from triggers or other classes that rely on them. When they're not available, your coverage drops because other test classes fail because the code isn't there when it's called upon to run.

Comment: I will look but I am not sure how removing class 'ABCsort' would make trigger 'LinkeXYZtoPDQ' suddenly show no coverage.

Comment: The overall code coverage is a red herring, and appears to be false in this case. What would seem to be the problem is a trigger that isn't being exercised at all.

Comment: greenstork, this appears correct. Can you elaborate a little? I would be happy with a class not being exercised - I don't want it hanging out in my org to potentially fire

Comment: If you don't need a class, you should delete it and deploy the deletion of the entire classes folder. The same for triggers.

Comment: I found the cause - I also needed to deploy Test Classes referencing the deleted class.